# Get latest record based on two fields

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table with the following fields:

```
user_id         year      month     amount    type
--------------------------------------------------
5               2018      1         100       Foo
6               2017      12        100       Bar
6               2018      11        100       Foo
6               2018      12        100       Bar
7               2018      12        100       Foo
7               2019      12        100       Bar
8               2019      12        100       Foo
```

I'm looking to do 3 things:

1. Get the latest record per user id (1 record, latest year and month field) for certain users,

something like:

```
select *
from myTable
where user_id in (6,7) and <is latest year / month>
```

which should return

```
user_id         year      month     amount     type
---------------------------------------------------
6               2018      12        100        Bar
7               2019      12        100        Foo
```

2. calculate totals for the above query, something like:

```
    select SUM(amount) as myTotal, avg(amount) as myAverage, 
    (count # of foos in result) as numberOfFoos,
    (count # of bars in result) as numberOfBars
    from myTable
    where user_id in (6,7) and <is latest year / month>
```

which would return one row with the custom fields:

```
myTotal     myAverage     numberOfFoos      numberOfBars
--------------------------------------------------------
300         100           2                 1
```

3. Same as above query, but for EVERY MONTH for a period of time, eg. for the last 3-5 years, ideally in the fewest calls possible, instead of looping through 36+ months manually and making separate calls.

```
    year     month    myTotal     myAverage     numberOfFoos      numberOfBars
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------
    2018     1        300         100           2                 1
    2018     2        300         100           2                 1
    2018     3        300         100           2                 1
    ...
    2020     12       300         100           2                 1
```

Comment: What did you try so far and what was wrong with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First problem can be solved using `row_number` function:

```
with d as (
  select 
    users.*, 
    row_number() over (partition by user_id  order by year desc, month desc ) rn 
  from  users 
  where  user_id in (5, 6)
) 
select * from d
where  rn = 1;
```

[PostgreSQL fiddle here](https://sqlize.online/?phpses=null&sqlses=760d517943e711b9a31c539ee268046b&php_version=null&sql_version=psql12)

Second problem can be solved using same way:

```
with d as (
  select 
    users.*, 
    row_number() over (partition by user_id  order by year desc, month desc) rn 
  from  users 
  where  user_id in (6, 7)
) 
select 
    sum(amount), avg(amount), 
    count(*) filter (where type = 'Foo') count_foo, 
    count(*) filter (where type = 'Bar') count_bar
from d
where  rn = 1;
```

[Test solution here](https://sqlize.online/?phpses=null&sqlses=6ec5b08c12f196540a33af385f3ef3da&php_version=null&sql_version=psql12)

Comment: Thanks, this did most of what I need, there is another use case I'm not sure how to do but I'll create a separate question before someone else complains.

Answer (score 1):

```
select year, month, sum(amount), avg(amount),
       sum(case when type = 'Foo' then 1 else 0 end) as num_foos,
       sum(case when type = 'Bar' then 1 else 0 end) as num_bars
from (select u.*, 
             row_number() over (partition by user_id  order by year desc, month desc ) as seqnum 
      from users 
      where user_id in (5, 6)
     ) u
where seqnum = 1
group by year, month;
```